# json con insercion de datos a db

Tags: json

Tengo varios archivos (php y js) sobre el juego de la ruleta. Un usuario juega y recibe x puntos. Pero dichos puntos no se guardan en ninguna base de datos ni tampoco en ningun archivo.

El archivo en cuestion que quiero añadir código es el archivo index.js el cual muestro a continuacion.

En el existen varios eventos, en uno de ellos deseo realizar una llamda 'onGameEnd' a este evento para introducir en mi base de datos informacion que me interesa como son los puntos generados por el usuario una vez que acaba de jugar.
El archivo PHP que tengo ya realizo la conexion a mi base de datos.
Por lo tanto solo me queda los INSERT de MySql para añadir a la db.

Perdonen si no me he explicado bien.

```
            function loadJSON(callback) {

          var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
          xobj.open('GET', './wheel_data.php', true); 
          xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {

              callback(xobj.responseText);
            }
          };
          xobj.send(null);
        }

         //Capturar los resultados del giro
        function myResult(e) {
          //e is the result object
            console.log('Spin Count: ' + e.spinCount + ' - ' + 'Win: ' + e.win + ' - ' + 'Message: ' +  e.msg);


        if(e.userData){

              console.log('User defined score: ' + e.userData.score)

            }
        }

        //Capturar cualquier error.
        function myError(e) {
          console.log('Spin Count: ' + e.spinCount + ' - ' + 'Message: ' +  e.msg);
        }

        function myGameEnd(e) {

          //'e' es gameResultsArray
          console.log(e);
          TweenMax.delayedCall(5, function(){

            Spin2WinWheel.reset();

          })


        }

        function init() {
          loadJSON(function(response) {

            var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);

            var mySpinBtn = document.querySelector('.spinBtn');

            var myWheel = new Spin2WinWheel();

            myWheel.init({data:jsonData, onResult:myResult, onGameEnd:myGameEnd, onError:myError, spinTrigger:mySpinBtn});

          });
        }

        //And finally call it
        init();
```

Comment: mira por favor [ask]. No se entiende mucho que queres hacer. Apreta el boton [edit] y explica mejor que queres hacer y cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Yo no entiendo que tiene que ver un insert de una db con un json

Comment: Ya he realizado un cambio en el texto. Perdonen las molestias

Comment: No es ninguna molestia... Sigo sin entender bien cual es el problema que tuviste para hacer el insert..

Comment: Tengo pocas nociones de Javascript, y no se donde colocar la sentencia (INSERT INTO) accediendo al objeto en concreto. La clave esta en la linea:    myWheel.init({data:jsonData, onResult:myResult, onGameEnd:myGameEnd, onError:myError, spinTrigger:mySpinBtn});

Comment: Si sabes tu como realizar el INSERT, dime como lo hago por favor. saludos

Comment: Ah ok. Para hacer el insert, el mismo lo tiene que hacer tu backend. Como esta estructurado el mismo? Como te conectas a la db? que lenguaje usas para el mismo?

Comment: OK, tengo un archivo principal que se llama spin.php donde me conecto mediante php a la base de datos (eso lo hace bien) y capturo la sesion del user: $id_user = $_SESSION['EX_login'];. Ademas tambien llamo al archivo 'index.js' (el que muestro el contenido arriba) para que se ejecute el 'juego de la ruleta'., y me interesa capturar los puntos que gana el usuario --> e.userData.score

Comment: Ya lo solucione con la $ajax dentro de myResult(e). Ahora funciona perfectamente y añade datos a db. Saludos

Comment: Agrega una respuesta a tu pregunta, que explique cual era el problema y cual la solucion. mira [answer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.
Resulta que en AndroidStudio han cambiado la ubicacion y denominacion del Explorador de Archivos.

- Antes estaba en Tools/ Android/ **Android Device Monitor**
- Y en versiones sucesivas (yo tengo la 3.6.3) se encuentra en View/ Tools Windows / **Device File Explorer.**

Y por eso no lo encontraba.
Espero que esto sirva para los que quieren encontrar de una manera rapida su base de datos para poder hacer comprobaciones.

Una vez en el Device File Explorer teneis que ir a:

data/data/Tu_proyecto[image: database]

Una vez entrado en el